# How can i show widgets depending whether it is parent or not in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show left sidebar widget, which is the list of sub pages if the page is a parent page. Else want to show the right sidebar.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is done:

```
if($post->post_parent == '') {
    //show the parent thing here
} else {
    //show the child thing here
}
```

Comment: Updated example - try it.